# Stop wildfly war from initializing mojarra

Tags: jsf, wildfly, wildfly-8, wildfly-10, mojarra

Whenever I deploy a war to wildfly 8 or 10 (in this case it's a jax-rs service), I see the following line

[javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 151) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.11-jbossorg-1 20150505-1501 for context

Since JSF is not used in the application, is there a way to stop mojarra from being initialized?

Comment: Do you have faces-config.xml file in your WEB-INF/ folder? This might have been an implicit dependency.

Comment: I did at one point, but removing it had no effect

Comment: Are you by chance including any JSF dependencies in your deployment?

Comment: None that I can see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove

`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>`

from your profile.
It should stop Mojarra initialization.

Comment: afaik, JSF is only 'enabled' if required (lazy loaded). So if you disable it like the answer suggests, I think you get different errors (since it does seem to be required in one way or another)

Comment: If its lazy loaded why is the class being initialized ? Have you tried this ?  Server boots up fine. I think you get different errors (since it does seem to be required in one way or another) Kindly try and then reply back, I'll wait

Answer (score 7):

Add a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to your WEB-INF folder to stop deployment for a single war

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="jsf" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I added it to the WEB-INF folder but it didn't have any effect. Do we have to add it to the WEB-INF folder or the META-INF folder ? I'm asking as the project I'm involved in, someone already has added a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in META-INF folder. Don't know if that works though.

Comment: The correct XML should have the namespace declaration:
xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3"